# Do not call document.ready on Nifi InvokeHTTP processor. What is the reason?

Tags: apache-nifi

When Https URL is read from Nifi invokeHttp, the result is saved as PutFile.
What I expected was the HTML of the URL, but it wasn't all complete.
Looking at the contents, the URL in the browser was "document.ready".
However, it did not work in nifi, so some combobox contents were not created.
Is there a way to read everything from nifi?

url: https://kauai.ccmc.gsfc.nasa.gov/DONKI/search/

Thanks for your help ^^;

Comment: are you expecting from nifi to execute javascript from downloaded page???

Comment: Are you not getting the HTML results that run automatically?